# Spring zuul proxy appends extra json response along with service response json

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Spring zuul proxy appends extra json response along with service response json

Below is the zuul configuration

```
zuul:
  sensitiveHeaders:
  routes:
    api-gateway:
      url: http://localhost:8099
    abc-management:
      url: http://localhost:8098
```

Below is the response json

```
{
    "status": "P200",
    "message": "Orders fetched successfully",
    "timeStamp": "2020-09-30T16:01:42.116275Z",
    "data": {
        "orders": [
            {
                "order_id": "11312553751504",
                "status_reason": null
            }
        ]
    },
    "requestId": 0
}{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-30T16:01:42.122+0000",
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api-gateway/orders"
}
```

The extra json

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-30T16:01:42.122+0000",
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api-gateway/orders"
}
```

is appended by zuul proxy, is this a bug or a misconfiguration

Comment: zuul doesn't append anything by default. Can you provide any more information such as versions and more configuration?

Comment: i was able to fix this by commenting the  
// @Bean
// public PostFilter  postfilter() {
//  return new PostFilter();
// } code

Comment: What's `PostFilter` and where did it come from?

Comment: the proxy server spring application class , i was overriding few methods
```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ProxyServerApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ProxyServerApplication.class, args);
 }
 
 @Bean
 public PreFilter  prefilter() {
  return new PreFilter();
 }
 
 
// @Bean
// public PostFilter  postfilter() {
//  return new PostFilter();
// }
// 
 
 @Bean
 public RouteFilter  routefilter() {
  return new RouteFilter();
 }
 
 
}
```

Comment: Then it can't be a bug in zuul if it's not code in zuul

Comment: ok,yea. may be a wrong configuration from code. but in it looks strange. simply overriding a postfilter its adding extra response json.

Comment: Your adding a post filter, not overriding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was overriding PostFilter, when that part is removed. It fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because an exception occurred in filter. and response has written twice, the response data and the /error response.

ApplicationFilterChain.java

```
        } catch (IOException | ServletException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e = ExceptionUtils.unwrapInvocationTargetException(e);
            ExceptionUtils.handleThrowable(e);
            throw new ServletException(sm.getString("filterChain.filter"), e);
        }
```

StandardWrapperValve.java

```
private void exception(Request request, Response response,
                       Throwable exception) {
    request.setAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION, exception);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    response.setError();
}
```

BasicErrorController.java

```
@RequestMapping
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpStatus status = this.getStatus(request);
    if (status == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
        return new ResponseEntity(status);
    } else {
        Map<String, Object> body = this.getErrorAttributes(request, this.getErrorAttributeOptions(request, MediaType.ALL));
        return new ResponseEntity(body, status);
    }
}
```

if these is an Error occurred in filter, then will be redirect to /error page.

this is a example:

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        throw new RuntimeException("error");
    }
}

@RestController
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public User user(@RequestParam int id) {
        return new User(id, "user" + id);
    }
}
```

Request from postman, the response:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "user2"
}{
    "timestamp": "2022-02-15T11:06:16.094+00:00",
    "status": 200,
    "error": "OK",
    "path": "/user"
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDwK3.png)